# Using angle attribute to split voronoi polygan to three small polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, voronoi-thiessen

I have a point data set, that include [id] and [angle] attribute, like 0/120/240。I made voronoi layer use point, i want to use angle attribute split voronoi polygan to three small polygan, how to do in QGIS or GRASS ?

I try to calculate max distance of one point and associate polygan, using distance and angle draw line,  next find interaction point of line and polygan edge,  last using interaction point split voronoi polygan.

the way is true ? 
How to do?